# Epress/Jade Site not allowing google font to be loaded in

Tags: html, css, node.js, fonts, pug

For some reason, nothing I'm doing is getting this to work.

Layout.jade file

```
  doctype html
  html
    head
      title= title

      link(rel='stylesheet',   href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css')
      link(rel='styelsheet', href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel:900|Lato:300i', type='text/css')
      link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/css/style.css')

    body
      include ./partials/_nav.jade
      block content
      include ./partials/_footer.jade
```

and portion of the nav that is rendered:

```
<span class="nav-item col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="./">Home</a></span>
```

and I have this css (shortened to just what one example)

```
.nav-item {
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    background-color:#333333;
    font-family: "Lato", serif;
}
```

All of the other properties that I assigned worked fine, so I'm rather confused why the font isn't working.  I thought maybe it had something to do with when exactly the fonts loaded? Maybe it gets rendered before the fonts are loaded in?

Thanks

Comment: Try to get rid of `, type='text/css'` and check the spaces in the first link `,       href='https://maxcdn`.

Answer (score 2):

Typo: `styelsheet`

```
link(rel='styelsheet', href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel:900|Lato:300i', type='text/css')
```